# How to get diskutil info output in a cocoa application

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, disk

Is there a way to programmatically get the same information that `diskutil info / | grep "Free Space"` gives you? (For obvious reasons I'd rather have a better way to do this than just parsing the result of that command.)

Currently I'm using `statfs`; however, it was brought to my attention that the space this reports is not always accurate, because OS X also places temporary files such as Time Machine snapshots on the drive. These files automatically get deleted if space is running out, and the OS does not report the usage of these files. In other words, `statfs` often gives a lower number of free space than `diskutil info` or looking at the disk information in Finder.

Comment: That is interesting about `statfs()` being inaccurate due Time Machine temp files.  I wonder how it does that?  Are you sure that's the case?

Comment: @trojanfoe: I believe `statfs` returns the "true" amount of free disk space there is. However, Finder "cheats" by showing a bit more free space, accounting for the fact some files would get deleted automatically. I have received bug reports about this, and it turns out this is the issue (narrowed it down to `df -h` reporting less free space than `diskutil info / | grep "Free Space"`)

Comment: diskutil is showing the same free space as df -H. df -h is using base 2 for sizes and df -H is using 10. See `man 1 df`.

Comment: `Wherever a size is supplied as an output, it is always presented as a base-ten
     approximation with one decimal digit and a base-ten SI multiplier`. That's from `man 8 diskutil`, that's why you see different sizes.

Comment: @IvanGenchev: that is not the case from my tests. Users are reporting that this : `(100.0 * (double)(stats.f_blocks - stats.f_bfree) / (double)stats.f_blocks)` gives a different free percentage than the Finder.

Comment: For more modern versions of macOS, change "Free Space" to "Available Space", since the output for diskutil has changed: `diskutil info / | grep "Available Space"`

Answer (score 9):

You can use `popen(3)`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *f;
    char info[256];

    f = popen("/usr/sbin/diskutil info /", "r");
    if (f == NULL) {
        perror("Failed to run diskutil");
        exit(0);
    }

    while (fgets(info, sizeof(info), f) != NULL) {
        printf("%s", info);
    }

    pclose(f);

    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT**

Sorry, I didn't read the question carefully. You can also use the [Disk Arbitration Framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/DOCUMENTATION/Darwin/Reference/DiscArbitrationFramework/_index.html). There's also some sample code that might be helpful ([FSMegaInfo](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/FSMegaInfo/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10004032)).

**UPDATE**

I took a look at the output from `otool -L $(which diskutil)` and it seems that it's using a private framework called `DiskManagement.framework`. After looking at the output from `class-dump` I saw there's a `volumeFreeSpaceForDisk:error:` method. So the sizes I got from `diskutil -info /` and `FSMegaInfo FSGetVolumeInfo /` and my tool were:

- diskutil: `427031642112 Bytes`
- my tool: `volumeFreeSpaceForDisk: 427031642112`
- FSMegaInfo: `freeBytes      = 427031642112 (397 GB)`

I also observed that the sizes differ (with a few KB) every time I ran one of the tools and also that `diskutil` is dividing by 1000 and `FSMegaInfo` is dividing by 1024, so the size in GB will be always different (same reason as with `df -h` and `df -H` and `diskutil` - base 10 and base 2).

Here's my sample tool:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "DiskManagement.h"
#import <DiskArbitration/DADisk.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int                 err;
    const char *        bsdName = "disk0s2";
    DASessionRef        session;
    DADiskRef           disk;
    CFDictionaryRef     descDict;
    session  = NULL;
    disk     = NULL;
    descDict = NULL;
    if (err == 0) {session = DASessionCreate(NULL); if (session == NULL) {err = EINVAL;}}
    if (err == 0) {disk = DADiskCreateFromBSDName(NULL, session, bsdName); if (disk == NULL) {err = EINVAL;}}
    if (err == 0) {descDict = DADiskCopyDescription(disk); if (descDict == NULL) {err = EINVAL;}}

    DMManager *dmMan = [DMManager sharedManager];
    NSLog(@"blockSizeForDisk: %@", [dmMan blockSizeForDisk:disk error:nil]);
    NSLog(@"totalSizeForDisk: %@", [dmMan totalSizeForDisk:disk error:nil]);
    NSLog(@"volumeTotalSizeForDisk: %@", [dmMan volumeTotalSizeForDisk:disk error:nil]);
    NSLog(@"volumeFreeSpaceForDisk: %@", [dmMan volumeFreeSpaceForDisk:disk error:nil]);

    return 0;
}
```

You can obtain the `DiskManagement.h` by running `class-dump /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DiskManagement.framework/Versions/Current/DiskManagement > DiskManagement.h` and you can link to that framework by including the private frameworks path using `-F/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/` and add `-framework`.

Compile:

```
clang -g tool.m -F/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ -framework Foundation -framework DiskArbitration -framework DiskManagement -o tool
```

**UPDATE2:**
You can also take a look [here](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4878) and [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/85805/how-to-wipe-huge-mobilebackups-folder). If the `FSMegaInfo` sample is not working for you, then you can just `stat` the `/Volumes/.MobileBackups` and subtract it's size from what you get from `statfs("/", &stats)`.

Comment: I found that on another question here, but it doesn't seem that framework actually provides free space info. If it does could you point me to a specific function?

Comment: Look at the sample, that I added in my answer and the `FileManager.c` in particular.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try sending that to the user who reported the bug and see if it's any better than what `statfs` does

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I think I'll go with just subtracting the size of the `.MobileBackups` as that seems easiest, in case the `FSMegaInfo` sample still reports the wrong size for the user who reported this.

Comment: See this - http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/kext_tools/kext_tools-268.13.1/update_boot.c, this - https://www.opensource.apple.com/source/kext_tools/kext_tools-252.2/update_boot.c and this - https://github.com/aosm/kext_tools/blob/master/update_boot.c. It seems that the `.MobileBackups` is in `/` and not in `/Volumes/` like some of the other articles suggest.

Comment: I just enabled the feature on my own machine (though I couldn't get it to actually back up anything as my drive is too full), and there are two places it is located it seems. There's `/.MobileBackups` and `/Volumes/MobileBackups`. In any case, still waiting for the customer to reply to see if this fixed the problem, I'll accept the answer once he does

Comment: THIS SAVED MY LIFE!!! I cannot explain how much this answer helped me. Just two small things: I had to change `int err;` to `int err = 0;` for the sample code to work, and neither `volumeTotalSizeForDisk:` nor `volumeFreeSpaceForDisk:` seem to work for me.

Comment: If the results for `volumeTotalSizeForDisk` or `volumeFreeSpaceForDisk` are coming back as `null`, then the `bsdName` is not a valid disk on your system (it might need to be changed to something like `disk1s1`).  I have created a GitHub Gist which modifies Ivan's code by determining the BSD name of the root disk.  https://gist.github.com/edenwaith/9b33103a0aa4aab63b7dee9f73fe49a3